# How can i display my data in a chart using chart js

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

Please help me i don't know how to display my data in chart bar, iam using ChartJs

This is my sell table

```html
id  | product     | stock | 
1   | brown cloth | 50    |
2   | jeans neavy | 35    |
```

This is my controller

```
public function chart2()
{
   $sell= DB::table('sell')->get();
       return view('myblade')>with('sell',json_encode($sell,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
}
```

I want to show the product as the label and the stok as the data, this the cart bar

```js
var db == {{ url('chart2') }}; // your db object
          var your_labels  = new Array();
          var your_data = new Array();  //array that will hold your data

          db.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
            your_labels.push(item.product);
            your_data.push(item.stock);
          })

          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: your_labels, 
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of stocks',
                    data: your_data, 
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",  //create them the same way. with same size 1 for each data entry
                    borderColor: color_border_array,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the canvas

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center"><b>Data Penjualan</b></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <canvas id="canvas" height="280" width="400"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can dynamically fill the label and data array from your database before initializing the chart and pass them instead of the static data.

Comment: can you give me the example code, iam new to this

Comment: you are new to what, javascript or programming?

Comment: iam new to javascript

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do a basic iteration over your db and initialize label and data array

```
var db; // your db object
var your_labels, your_data;  //array that will hold your data

db.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
  your_labels.push(item.product);
  your_data.push(item.stock);
})
```

pass them in your chart in initialization like this.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: your_labels, 
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of stocks',
                    data: your_data, 
                    backgroundColor: color_background_array,  //create them the same way. with same size 1 for each data entry
                    borderColor: color_border_array,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

The important point to remember is you will have to see the iteration of db object on your own. I don't know what and how are you using it.

Comment: Hi it's just turn out to be blank, there is no chart that display

Comment: you have created color_background_array and color_border_array right?

Comment: yeah i have made it

Comment: ```var db == {{ url('chart2') }}; ```

 "==" why have you used a comparison operator? 

Try to debug the code on your own. if you are running it on chrome you can right-click and use the inspect option. you will the js errors in the console section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203263/discussion-between-sarthak-ssg5-and-evvnnxx18).